# How to set number of retries in Tibco JMS Client Acknowledge mode

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

we have an application that is configured to work in CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode of TIBCO JMS queue. Now we want to put a limit on number of times a message can be redelivered.

Answer (score 1):

To configure re-delivery of messages you need to configure the "maxRedelivery" on the destination.

For more detailed instructions look at the Tibco user guide under "Chapter 2 Destinations" -> "Destination Properties" -> maxRedelivery.

[tibco user guide](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.3.0/doc/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)